# Photoshop 3D - creating textures to the correct size for each face

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

Is there a way to create new face textures, in Photoshop 3D, that match the dimensions of the objects face.

By default the original texture, for the face of an object, is set the dimensions of the original. For example, if I create a cube, then scale it to be more like a cuboid the textures of each face because skewed and is no longer proportionally scaled. If I select the face I wish to texture, and go Displace>New Texture, the dimensions of this new texture at set to a default arbitrary height and width--usually what the size of the last document was that I created.

The reason I am asking this, is because I'm trying to use Photoshop 3D for retail visualisations, where I often need to create a single 3D object that then gets put into various in situ photos. However I need the faces of the modelled object to be at a 1:1 proportional scale and not skewed in anyway, so that I can design each surface as though it was designed as a flat graphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've found is to use the 3D Properties panel to get the size of each face for a given object. Ie. WxHxD.

Using these dimensions, create a new or edit an existing texture and use the Image > Canvas Size tool to resize the texture's canvas from the default dimensions, to those obtained from the 3D Properties panel.

It's not an ideal fix, but seems to work pretty well.